# Entity Framework: Overload resolution failed because no accessible ORDERBY can be called with these arguments

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Please see the code below:

```
Public Function GetMembers(Optional ByVal sortExpression As String = "MemberId ASC") As List(Of Member) 'Implements IMemberDao.GetMembers
        Using context = New LibraryDBEntities()
            Dim members = context.Members.AsQueryable.OrderBy(sortExpression).ToList
            Return Mapper.Map(Of List(Of MemberEntity), List(Of Member))(members)
        End Using
    End Function
```

The error I get is: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible ORDERBY can be called with these arguments".  I am new to Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is not dynamic enough to handle sort conditions specified as strings. A call of `OrderBy` takes an expression, not a string. The expression takes an object, and produces an expression that maps to a column on which to sort the output:

```
Dim members = context.Members.AsQueryable.OrderBy(Function(member) member.MemberId).ToList
```

Moreover, you cannot specify if a sort is to be ascending or descending in your sort expression: for sorting in ascending order use `OrderBy`; for sorting in descending order use `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy expects an Expression argument, not a string. What you should have written is:

```
context.Members.AsQueryable().OrderBy(m => m.MemberId);
```

For descending:

```
context.Members.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(m => m.MemberId);
```

This tells Entity Framework to order by the MemberId property of the Member class (I assume the Members property is a Queryable of Member).
Of course, then you have to rewrite the GetMembers() method so to translate the sortExpression you pass to it to a valid .Net Expression.